# phpBB manualy create forum posts with SQL query

Tags: sql, phpbb

I create a WordPress plugin and I like to post posts from WordPress in phpBB forums. As I know there is no any bridge that can do that in the WordPress phpBB latest versions. Now my question is:

How can I create posts into phpBB database manualy by building the SQL queries and execute them. Is there any good tutorial ? Do you have to sugest anything ?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which version of PHPBB are you using? If it's newer than version 3, perhaps you can use its API to submit a post. This should be much cleaner than inserting data into the database directly.

Here's a link to the post submission API: http://wiki.phpbb.com/Function.submit_post

Here's a tutorial to get you started with using the API: http://wiki.phpbb.com/Tutorial.Adding_pages

Comment: I use the latest phpBB version 3.0.9 so I have to look into your link ! Thanks ! :)

Comment: I've added a link to a tutorial which helps you get started with the api as well.